# AS3 - I am a newbie and try to find the way to find flv url from external domain to jwplayer.swf

Tags: actionscript-3, video, streaming, jwplayer, flv

I am working of video project where i have an requirement and stuck.

Looking for AS3 tutorial or documentation where it helps me to solve the problem.

I am an newbie in flash and trying to find the way to load flv url from external domain to jwplayer.swf.

In external domain html path of flv file will not be same, it will be changing for every refresh.

I tried to get flv path using asp.net and load the flv to jwplayer using flashvar, but it said ip address doesn't match.

So we need to fetch the flv from clientside and play it using jwplayer.

example:

I am trying to get flv file path from below url using client side script (as3 or alternative asp.net) and pass the flv path to play in jwplayer.

http://www.uploadc.com/gviznjrk4uw5/never.ever.do.this.at.home.s01e12..flv.htm
or
http://www.uploadc.com/embed-gviznjrk4uw5.html

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Are you trying to embed the JW Player inside of another SWF?

Comment: no i am trying to pass the flv url to jwplayer by using proxy swf

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are trying to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked the crossdomain file?
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

Comment: i found gkplugins, and i see that they provide proxy.swf

example:
<param value="/jwplayer/player.swf" name="show">
<param value="plugins=/proxy.swf&amp;proxy.link=http://www.uploadc.com/gviznjrk4uw5/never.ever.do.this.at.home.s01e12..flv.htm&amp;proxy.noloading=false&amp; name="FlashVars">

This proxy.swf will get the flv url from http://www.uploadc.com/gviznjrk4uw5/never.ever.do.this.at.home.s01e12..flv.htm and load it to jwplayer to play.

So Mr. Ethan, Mr. Harrison i am looking to add one like proxy.swf?